# Memory issue when Pushing and Popping UINavigationController in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

I have two view controllers VC1 and VC2. i try to push VC2 by creating object of VC2 and pushing it on button action.

```
VC2 *vcOject = [[VC2 alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcOject animated:YES];
[vcObject release];
```

in VC2 i am popping it in button action..

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

now i am in VC1 and again Pushing VC2 for display. but this time i am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. but when i commented [vcObject release]. it works fine. but when can i release memory. how memory is handling in navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **You should be using ARC**.

If for whatever reason you can't, your view controller is deallocated once it's popped off the stack, and you should alloc/init a new one every time you want to push it on to the stack. Or if you don't want to do that - say, if the view in VC2 is very heavy - get rid of your `[vcObject release]` and keep a reference to `vcObject` in VC1, and keep pushing the same one on to the stack. Make sure you don't mix these two, though; if you create a new object every time you must release it after pushing it on to the stack, and if you are keeping a reference to push the same VC2 on the stack each time, you must not release it until VC1's `dealloc`. Keep in mind that you *must* release it in VC1's `dealloc` method, or else the memory will be leaked.

But, really. **You should be using ARC.**

Comment: i am working in xcode 4.0 (ios 4). so i am not using ARC. when will the dealloc menthod called. when i push/pop a view controller, it is not getting called. so how can i release it. i am using your second suggestion. i am keeping a reference of a object.so that the next time it will just push a same object. but dealloc method is not getting called..

Comment: The dealloc method is called when your view controller is deallocated. You're not in charge of that, the runtime is, so just rest assure that it will be called when it needs to be. In practicality this is either when your controller's view is removed from the view hierarchy, or when the application terminates. As long as you do it right you won't leak any memory.

One of the things no-one tells you about writing Objective-C is that you need to override dealloc for every class you write, and release all your instance variables.

Comment: By the way, you can use ARC with iOS 4.3, but it's a bit crippled so I get why you might not want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `[vcObject release]`. it will cause memory leaking to your application.

so, This is the way to handle memory management with push/pop viewController without using **ARC**

```
VC2 *vcOject = [[VC2 alloc] init];
[[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcOject animated:YES] autorelease];
```